# Visual Studio 2019 закрывается с ошибкой при простом печатании в редакторе

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image: Один из моментов где возникает ошибка]
Сейчас я введу "m" и студия вылетит и появится это:
[image: Ошибка]
Я переустанавливал все элементы .Net.
И чистил реестры и так далее, но это все что предлагает интернет.
Что делать вообще не понятно.
UDP:
Также вот лог файл: 
[лог файл](https://yadi.sk/d/JgZS0TSrL5K9DA)
UDP2:
Переустановил студию, не помогло.
Что делать?

Comment: Логи студии глядели? Саму студию переставляли?

Comment: в Log файлах пусто. Я не очень  понимаю что там должно быть, но там нет ничего за сегодня, что странно. Переустановка в моем случае займет дня полтора и я хотел бы решить это без таких долгих мер.

Comment: загляните в системые события. Больше, по идее, предложить нечего, только разве что гуглить ошибку.

Comment: В системных события ничего сопутствующего нет.

Comment: Может у вас какие-нибудь мусорные расширения установлены, например решарпер

Comment: [расширения](https://i.imgur.com/8uAJ4Uo.png) Вот мои расширения. Я так понимаю, что они из коробки шли.